# Invalid use of function error

Tags: c++, function, class, compiler-errors, static

I'm working on functions to move an "ant" north, south, east, or west on a 2D array. I have the functions done in a class I built for this "ant" but when I try to use the functions I keep getting "Invalid use of non-static member function".

```
Erno game;
```

This is how I called the class in the main function.

```
if(movement == 'N')
        game.move_N;
```

This is how I'm calling my functions from the class in main.

```
void move_N ()
    {
        if(row-1 < 0)
        {
            cout << "ERNO CANT MAKE THAT MOVE. PLEASE TRY A DIFFERENT MOVE. (S/E/W/.)";

        }
        else
            row -=1;
```

Finally, this is how I have the functions written in the class. All of the directions are the same pseudo code. They are also in the private sector.

Im new to classes so any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: s/`game.move_N;`/`game.move_N();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the call operator: `game.move_N();`

Comment: Thanks! Can’t believe I didn’t realize that myself.